# Reusing thread and UdpClient for sending and receiving on same port

Tags: c#

I am try to  Reusing thread and `UdpClient` for sending and receiving on same port but when i am calling the Method..

```
private void RecivedCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        if (ar == cuurentsynResult)
        {
            UdpClient c = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).c;
            IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;
            Byte[] buffer = c.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
            if (buffer.Length > 0)
                System.Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
            UdpState s = new UdpState(e, c);
            cuurentsynResult = udpclient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(RecivedCallback), s);                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string str = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

I have facing the exception is that..
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
so how i can resolve this problem.please send your opinion or answers

Sonu Ranjan

Comment: UDP is not connection-based. How could a connection be closed then? The error is probably occurring elsewhere. Please post the full exception including stack trace and mark the line where it is thrown. Remove the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

On a UDP socket, that error likely means you received a Port Unreachable ICMP message in response to a datagram you sent.

How you recover from that will be application specific.